# Rails and Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf-protection

- rails 4.2.6
- ruby 2.3

I'm having some difficulty to implement the [rack-protection gem](https://github.com/sinatra/rack-protection) with rails.

The AuthenticityToken protection was enabled in this way:

```
#application.rb

module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.middleware.use Rack::Protection
        config.middleware.use Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken
    end
end
```

The problem is that I aways get a "Forbidden" when logging with Devise gem.

`WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken`

However the "csrf_meta_tags" are present on the top of every page:

```
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="+4lRTVfIWBjsgGXEzHFVCIf/Bi/jqqfkLPg6qdw5FMHA1L3Eh36I+hALcRIhv1VjfgTznssJqvRh+/IEMhyNeA==">
</head>
```

And the authenticity_token is passed as an input hidden inside the session form too:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" value="+4lRTVfIWBjsgGXEzHFVCIf/Bi/jqqfkLPg6qdw5FMHA1L3Eh36I+hALcRIhv1VjfgTznssJqvRh+/IEMhyNeA==" type="hidden">
```

What am I missing here?

**I'm in development mode, not production.**

Thanks!